# HTML button submit not activating php code

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having an issue with my html forms not submitting properly. I am new to forms and have been trying to get a login script going but it has been failing. I am using chrome mostly. Here is the super dumbed down code that hopefully demonstrates my issue. I am guessing what is wrong in this code is in the extended code. This is the website I used for my login coding: [login account setup site mainly for reference](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/php-login-and-registration-script-with.html)

```
<?php

//this is here for testing
session_start();

//this shows
echo "something";

//none of these show
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    echo "something";
    echo "something";
    echo "something";
    echo "something";
}
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){

    echo "something";
    echo "something";
    echo "something";
    echo "something";
}if(isset($_POST['submit3'])){

    echo "something";
    echo "something";
    echo "something";
    echo "something";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<footer>
    <!-- I have tried it with and without an action -->
    <form action="button_test.php" method="post" id="this" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: darkblue;">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit">this is something</button>
        <button type="button" name="submit2" id="submit2" class="button" value="this">this is something2</button>
        <input type="button" name="submit3" id="submit3" class="button" value="true"/>
    </form>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The first button predictably reloads the page, while the others do nothing. This is the extended main code that I need working. Once again, I am guessing the code above probably explains what is wrong with the code beneath. The code beneath is primarily there to give context and more accurate answers.

```
<?php

//require once the DatabaseController.php file,
require_once 'Controllers/DatabaseController.php';
echo "this happend1";
// Creates a data connect object that creates a connection to
// a database
$connection = new DataConnect;
//Run the user_load function to set the user
$connection->user_load();
echo "this happend2";
/*
 * Runs the in_loggedin function from a
 * user object and checks if it is blank
 */
if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    echo "this happend3";
    //return user to logged in home page if
    //they are logged in
    $user->redirect('index.php');
}
echo "this happend4";
/*
 * THIS DOES NOT WORK FOR SOME REASON
 */
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    echo "this happend5";
    //Load the variables with the new form data that has been executed
    $uname = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
    $umail = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
    $upass = $_POST['txt_password'];

    //If the user->login call is successful, go to home fully logged in
    if($user->login($uname,$umail,$upass))
    {
        //Go to home, fully logged in
        $user->redirect('index.php');
    }
    else
    {
        //Error
        $error = "Wrong Details !";
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Josiah</title>

        <link href="Assets/Stylesheets/styles-home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include_once 'header.php';
        ?>

<!-- recent blog post: contains the most recent blog post-->
<div id="main-content" class="content">
    <div id="main-content-inner" class="inner-content">
        <!-- this is the container for the form -->
        <div class="form-container">
            <!-- create a form that uses the "post" method which allows php to do $_POST on
            corresponding variable names -->
            <form method="post">

                <h2>Sign in.</h2><hr />
                <!-- checks if there was an error. If the error variable is set -->
                <?php
                if(isset($error))
                {
                    ?>
                    <!-- displays the error -->
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?> !
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
                <!-- this is a form-group -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- this is a text input. -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_uname_email" placeholder="Username or E mail ID" required />
                </div>
                <!-- this is a form-group -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- this is a text input. -->
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txt_password" placeholder="Your Password" required />
                </div>
                <!-- splits parts of the form -->
                <div class="clearfix"></div><hr />
                <!-- this is a form group holdng the submit button -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- the button interestingly has multiple classes -->
                    <button type="submit" name="btn-login" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                        <!-- splits parts of the form. Dont know specifically what this does. -->
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>&nbsp;SIGN IN
                    </button>
                </div>
                <br />
                <label>Don't have account yet ! <a href="sign-up.php">Sign Up</a></label>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- footer: contains social media, site map, and an up arrow-->
<?php
include 'footer.php'
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let's test: at the top of the script you do `var_dump($_POST)` and `echo file_get_contents('php://input')`, what shows up at each line?

Comment: I get: array(0) { } submit=Submit

Comment: It seems to be going by button value, but I want it to go by the button name, which I though it did. The website I referenced and the extended code does not make use of a value field in the button, which I feel I would like to keep that way unless absolutely needed. It seems that the if statement

Comment: check out my answer

Comment: Does my top code work on other people's  computers? I tried this code on two computers now and neither work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some searching I forgot to disclose that I was using PHPstorm. The reason why this did not occur to me is that PHPstorm is not installed on another computer that I have been using, however since I use Intellij on both computers, this bug in PHPstorm transferred regardless since Intellij will use PHPstorm plugins. It seems that 10.1-10.3 this bug persists where POST remains empty. I am not sure if it was fixed so I moved over to Apache and have it doing the web serving instead. Everything works, or at least works better. The 2 solutions are either wait for PHPstorm to fix this bug, or better move over to Apache.

[link to site post](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31257)

Answer (score 0):

Since `php://input` shows the form value (according to the test I had you run in comments), we know that PHP is properly receiving the data.

By default, PHP will place request parameters in `$_GET` and `$_POST` as appropriate. In your case this doesn't seem to be happening.  I suggest you look at your `php.ini` file and add the setting below:

```
variables_order = "GPCS"
```

There may already be a `variables_order` line, so just edit it in that case ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order)).

Comment: It wasn't commented either right? (preceded by `;`). If so, uncomment it. You'll also need to restart PHP for any change to take effect.

Comment: Yeah it was already there. The $_POST has always worked fine. I set "$_POST['this thing'] = 6;" before the var dump, set one of the if statements to "if(isset($_POST['this thing']))" and it works. It seems the html form is not setting post. If I move the "$_POST['this thing'] = 6;" to the end of the page then nothing happens.

Comment: I could try splitting the php into an entirely different file then calling when the button is pressed, but I feel that I am supposed to be able to use them in one file as the website had

Comment: Setting `$_POST['x']` within the script and reading it back doesn't tell us whether `$_POST` works. The test is: does PHP auto-fill it with values received from the form.  If you add another `<input type='text'>` in the form and fill it with text, does the text show up in: 1) `var_dump($_POST)`  2) `var_dump($_REQUEST)` or 3) `echo file_get_contents('php://input')` (of course put all those lines at the beginning of the script)

Comment: The text does not show in any. The echo file_get_contents('php://input') says submit=Submit which is referring to the first submit button. The others are empty arrays. Here is the linein my ini: 
; paid for the registration of these arrays and because ENV is not as commonly
; used as the others, ENV is not recommended on productions servers. You
; can still get access to the environment variables through getenv() should you
; need to.
; Default Value: "EGPCS"
; Development Value: "GPCS"
; Production Value: "GPCS";
; http://php.net/variables-order
variables_order = "GPCS"

Comment: From your post it's difficult to say what your `php.ini` looks like. It seems you posted comments from the file instead of the actual configuration. Any line that begins with a semi-colon `;` is ignored. The line from my answer should be by itself, with nothing else on the same line before or after it. And again, PHP must be restarted if you make any change there.

Comment: It is by itself "variables_order = "GPCS"" on its own line, without the outer quotes, everything else is just comments. This was from a development template

Comment: @JosiahL. Ok. Don't know what's wrong. If I have another idea I'll post it here. Please do the same when you know more so I can learn from you.

Comment: @JosiahL. just thought of one thing. Maybe the `php.ini` you were looking at isn't the right one? If you put `phpinfo();exit;` at the top of your script, then run it and look through the ouput for the `Loaded configuration file`, does it refer to the `php.ini` you looked at earlier?

Comment: It is C:\WINDOWS\php.ini , and it also says farther down the var order is GPCS